# pdf2htmlEX is not recognized in the py script

Tags: python

In the cmd I type the following to run the test script provided in pdf2htmlEX as :

python test.py

It is giving me the following error:

**'pdf2htmlEX' is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

The test.py script is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


DIR = 'test_data'



import os
import sys


with open('out2.html','w') as outf:
    outf.write('<!DOCTYPE html>\n<html><head><meta charset=\"utf-8\"></head><body><div style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:80%;height:100%;"><iframe width="100%" height="100%" name="pdf"></iframe></div><div style="position:absolute;top:0;right:0;width:20%;height:100%;overflow:auto;text-align:right;">')

    for f in os.listdir(DIR):
        if not f.lower().endswith('.pdf'):
            continue
        print f
        if os.system('pdf2htmlEX -l 10 --no-drm 1 --fit-width 1024 --dest-dir html --external-hint-tool="ttfautohint" "%s/%s"' % (DIR,f)) != 0:
            print "error on ", f
            sys.exit(-1)

        ff = f[:-3]
        outf.write('<a href="html/%shtml" target="pdf">%s</a><br/>' % (ff,ff))
        outf.flush();

    outf.write('</div></body></html>')
```

The  test-data directory contains pages-2.pdf file.
Why am I getting the error and how can I successfully run this script?

Comment: Can you run pdf2htmlEX from the command line or identify it with the which command? If you can, check the default path that os.system uses to make sure that it is in the path. If you do not have it in your path try using the absolute address of the command.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how exactly can I do that? I am new to python.

Comment: Use command line to actually check if the script is actually found in you system. I am assuming that you are running a Linux system (or something similar). From the command line, use "which pdf2htmlEX" If it cannot find it to execute, check the exact file that is to be used and see if putting the full name and path in the command line will allow it to execute. Once you verify that you have it executing **by hand** from the command line, then you can try running it from the python script. Note when running from the command line, put it the parameters explicitly.

Comment: Another possibility is that pdf2htmlEX is not marked as executable. In that case double check what "ls -l" shows. Is it pdf2htmlEX or pdf2htmlEX.py as a save file? Is it marked as executable? Do you have the correct permissions set?

Comment: A search for pdf2htmlEX shows that it is an independent program that you would need to install on your platform. You would need to determine where in the path it is installed and how your platform PATH environment variable is set up. You would need to have the location it has been installed in in that PATH.